# Why is my boolean always true when passing it as value to a radio component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

so I am learning vue and have spent some time going through the documents and haven't seen the answer that solves my question. A lot of this is due to the nomenclature between using the CLI(which I am) and not.

I am trying to make it so that when one radio button is clicked it shows a div and when the other one is clicked it shows the other. Here is what I have.

Template:

```
<div id="daySelection">
    <div class="o-m-day">
        <div id="oneDay">
            <p>One day?</p><input v-model="selected" type="radio" name="oneDay" id="" class="r-button" value="true"> 
        </div>
        <div id="multipleDays">
            <p>Multiple days?</p> <input v-model="selected" type="radio" name="multDays" id="" class="r-button" value="false">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- the div where the conditional render will be rendered -->
    <div>
        <!-- multiple days -->
        <div v-show="selected" id="ta-multDays">
            <textarea  rows="10" cols="80" name="multDays" type="text" />
        </div>
        <!-- one day -->
        <div v-show="!selected" id="i-oneDay">
            <input type="text" name="r-oneDay">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
export default {
    name: 'CreateTournamentForm',
    data: function(e) {
        return {
            selected: Boolean,
        }
    },
}
```

above I was getting an error in the console that was saying that data needs to be a function that returns a new instance. I see many people and examples using vue instances differently where it is:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        selected: true,
    }
});
```

However whenever trying this Vue sends me a warning saying that it needs to be a function.

> [Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.

I am also aware that v-show toggles the display so I have tried both setting the display of the divs to:

```
display: none;
```

as well as not.

Comment: This may be a detail, but I suggest using `v-if` and `v-else` instead of `v-show` in your case. That way, if you need to change the conditions, you will have only 1 line to edit instead of 2, and if the condition becomes long the code will be simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the value of `selected` is a string, whereas you expect it to be a boolean.

The following watcher:

```
watch: {
    selected(newValue) {
        console.log("selected changed to", newValue, "which is a", typeof newValue);
    }
}
```

Will tell you this:

```
selected changed to true which is a string 
selected changed to false which is a string
```

The reason is that you give the fields `value` a string instead of a boolean. To fix this, instead of writing `value="true"`, write `:value="true"`.

You can play with a live example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/7z7lr2r23q).

Comment: Thanks, I got it a little before you posted the help but thanks. I thought that using bind with type convert it but after playing around with it I saw that it was a string. Thanks a lot of your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems as far as I can see here:

In a component, the `data` key must be a function and the value for the `selected` key in the object returned by the `data` function must be an actual boolean value `true` or `false` (which will be initial value)

```
export default {
  name: 'CreateTournamentForm',
  data: function(e) {
      return {
        selected: true,
    }
  },
}
```

By default, v-model values are treated as strings so your `true` and `false` values are actually the strings `"true"` and `"false"` which are both truthy. Changing your template code to the below (or alternatively using a number or string value instead) should fix it

```
<div v-show="selected === 'true'" id="ta-multDays">
    <textarea  rows="10" cols="80" name="multDays" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing it from a 'v-show' to 'v-if'

```
<div>
    <p>One day?</p>
    <input 
        v-model="selected" 
        type="radio" 
        name="oneDay" 
        id="oneDay" 
        class="r-button" 
        value="onlyOneDay" /> 
</div>
<div id="multipleDays">
    <p>Multiple days?</p> 
    <input 
        v-model="selected" 
        type="radio" 
        name="multDays" 
        id="multDays" 
        class="r-button" 
        value="multipleDays" />
</div>
```

then the div to be shown as follows:

```
<div v-if="selected === 'multipleDays'" id="ta-multDays">
    <textarea  rows="10" cols="80" name="" type="text" />
</div>

<div v-if="selected === 'onlyOneDay'" id="i-oneDay">
    <input type="text" name="">
</div>
```